# codenameone wait dialog

Tags: java-me, dialog, progressdialog, codenameone

I want to show a dialog for a while (for instance 2 seconds) when some event happened like when SMS received and after 2 seconds it hide automatically.

How can I do it in codenameone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dialog` class has a `show()` method that accepts a timeout as one of its arguments. If I remember correctly there is also a way to `setTimeout` on the dialog instance.

Comment: That's my fault that I didn't see correctly all parameters, by the way Thanks Shai.